Down-scaling image at each step in LoG blob detection
I'm new to CV. I'm currently implementing the LoG blob detection. I've come across this repo on Github: BlobDetector.
The main implementation is here: Blob.
I'm confused by the down-scaling of image in each step. I thought that by scaling the sigma, we are good to detect blobs at different size, then why do we need to scale the image. Please explain (intuitively, if possible). Sorry if this a bad question.
